# Convert mysql sub query to Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

How I can convert mysql query to laravel query? this is the query

```
SELECT
  users.first_name,
  users.id AS uid,
  (
  SELECT
    COUNT(vpl_submissions.accept)
  FROM
    vpl_submissions
  INNER JOIN vpl ON vpl_submissions.vpl = vpl.id
  WHERE vpl.courseid = 2 
    AND vpl_submissions.accept = 1 
    AND vpl_submissions.userid = uid
) AS completed
FROM
  users
INNER JOIN course_enroles ON users.id = course_enroles.user_id
WHERE course_enroles.course_id = 2
```

Comment: Have you looked at using `Eloquent` by any chance? https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/7 https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
    DB::table('users')
        ->join('course_enroles', 'users.id', '=', 'course_enroles.user_id')
        ->where("course_enroles.course_id", "=", 2)
        ->select(users.first_name,users.id AS uid,
            DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(vpl_submissions.accept) FROM 
                    vpl_submissions INNER JOIN vpl ON vpl_submissions.vpl = vpl.id 
                     WHERE vpl.courseid = 2 
                           AND vpl_submissions.accept = 1 
                           AND vpl_submissions.userid = uid) as completed")
           )
        ->get();
```

This will help you.

Comment: Thanks Working fine

Answer (score 0):

Until you find a better solution, you can run raw queries like this

```
$result = DB::select(DB::raw("
    select users.first_name,users.id AS uid,
    (
        select count(vpl_submissions.accept) 
        FROM vpl_submissions 
        INNER JOIN vpl on vpl_submissions.vpl = vpl.id 
        WHERE vpl.courseid=2 AND vpl_submissions.accept =1 
        AND vpl_submissions.userid = uid
    ) as completed 
    from users 
    inner join course_enroles on users.id = course_enroles.user_id 
    where course_enroles.course_id = 2
"));
```